# MySQL insert executed successfully and return ID, But not saving data sometimes while concurrency

Tags: mysql, concurrency, yii

I am suffering from one weird issue.
I am using MySQL Enterprise Server VERSION 8.

I have one API, which is doing following statements in Mysql database :

```
START TRANSACTION;
Many select statements;
INSERT INTO ... VALUES(...);
COMMIT;
Many select statements;
```

This is doing insert in one table and retrieve ID of newly created record in table.
This is working perfectly when this api is called when there is low load on server.

**But when Server load increase, Then it is executed well and also returning newly created record ID, But it is not saving record in database.**

**Currently, If I am calling this API 25 times from front-end simultaneously, Then This issue is occurred for 1 to 2 times. i.e. I can see all queries and transactions in Logs and all gives ID of record, But 1-2 records are not saved in database.**

Can anyone help me on this if any idea?

Answer (score 0):

When I deal with high concurrency, I use the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement. That might solve your problem.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

But the data is not inserted into the database, but the server did not report an error why

Comment: No, I can't use this as I don't have to update if key is exist.
Currently if I call API, then all success and those are providing IDs in sequence only and not duplicate as that's Auto-increment Primary key ID.

Comment: No, this operation just follows the principle of idempotence. You should judge in the code
`if isExist()
    toUpdate()
else 
    toInsert()`
When concurrent, there is no guarantee that the `isExist()` method will get the correct result, so `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is used.
Note that `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is only used in `toInsert()`, not needed in `toUpdate()`, and this is also Not an update statement. 
It only guarantees that there is only one record for the same `primary key` when inserting.